# WPF Give every new button the same click command using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Title says it all. Here's what I tried but the new buttons do nothing when I click them. Im new to WPF so feel free to relay any glaring bad practices you can see.

**UserInputPage.xaml**

```
<Grid Name="UserInputGrid">               
    <Button Name="FindAddressButton_1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,35,0,0" Width="30" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="left" Click="ClickFindAddress">...</Button>
    <Button Name="NewFileButton" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,6,0,0" Width="Auto" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="ClickNewBar">New Item</Button>        
</Grid>
```

**UserInputPage.xaml.cs**

```
    private void ClickNewBar (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FilesList.Items.Count < MAX_ADDRESS_BARS)
        {                
            CreateNewAddressBar();
            CreateFindButton();
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show (ErrorMessages.MAX_ITEMS);
        }
    }

    private void CreateFindButton()
    {
        Button newAddressButton = new Button();   
        newAddressButton.Name = buttonProperties.GetLatestRankedName();         
        newAddressButton.Content = AFindButtonsProperties.CONTENT;
        newAddressButton.Command = buttonProperties.ButtonsAction;
        UserInputGrid.Children.Add (newAddressButton);
    }
```

**AFindButtonsProperties.cs**

```
    public const int ROW = 0;
    public const int COLUMN = 1;
    public const double WIDTH = 30;
    public const double HEIGHT = 20;
    public const double MARGIN_INCREMENT = 22;
    public const string CONTENT = "...";
    public const string NAME = "FindAddressButton";

    public readonly VerticalAlignment verticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    public readonly HorizontalAlignment horizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    public readonly ICommand ButtonsAction;

    public AFindButtonsProperties (Grid inputGrid)
    {
        gridReference = inputGrid;
        int notNeeded;
        buttonReference = GetReferenceLastRankedButton (out notNeeded);
        ButtonsAction = buttonReference.Command;
    }

    private Button GetReferenceLastRankedButton (out int lastRank)
    {
        Button outputButton = null;
        int lastRankConstruction = 0;

        foreach (var element in gridReference.Children)
        {
            Button currentButton = element as Button;

            if (currentButton != null) //skipps elements that arent buttons
            {
                string[] choppedUp = currentButton.Name.ToString().Split ('_');

                if (choppedUp.Length > 1 && //prevents exception for names not following the FindButton convention.
                    choppedUp[0].Contains (NAME))
                {
                    int numberIsolated = Convert.ToInt16 (choppedUp[1]);

                    if (numberIsolated > lastRankConstruction)
                    {
                        outputButton = currentButton;
                        lastRank = numberIsolated;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (outputButton == null)
        {
            throw new ViewElementNotFoundException ("Cant find any buttons in the grid reference which follow the naming convention.");
        }

        else
        {
            lastRank = lastRankConstruction;
            return outputButton;
        }
    }

    public string GetLatestRankedName()
    {
        int lastRank;
        Button lastButton = GetReferenceLastRankedButton (out lastRank);
        lastRank++;
        string name = NAME + "_" + lastRank.ToString();
        return name;
    }
```

Comment: So this is a duplicate question but heres the answer to my query : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102760/wpf-button-click-in-c-sharp-code?rq=1

Comment: If you just want to use the click event why bother with the commands! I was sooo lost in your question!

Comment: Because of its summary  tool tip, I thought that Command was the click event. Your answer is very good though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Since you said you want better practices I put this here as an answer but, know that it doesn't address your approach.

As far as I could understand from code fractions you posted you want a pattern of controls (i.e. a text box and a button) repeated a number of times. To do that you must use an appropriate control. One of the best ones for such tasks is `ListView`.

The best way to use it is that you create a model for each element. For example let's say you have a model like this:

```
public class AModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public ICommand ClickCommand { get; set; }
}
```

All right using such a model I then create an `ObservableCollection` of this in the page that I want to use them:

```
public var list = new ObservableCollection<AModel>();
```

And add elements to it using the code you already have:

```
private void ClickNewBar (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (list.Count < MAX_ADDRESS_BARS)
    {                
        list.Add(new AModel()
            {
                Text = "",
                ICommand = SomeCommand
            });
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show (ErrorMessages.MAX_ITEMS);
    }
}
```

And know that you also have a command stored as `SomeCommand`. Next step is to render this using `ListView`. For that you are gonna need to create an item template specifying how WPF should render each element in your list.

```
<ListView ItemsSource={binding list}>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Name="UserInputGrid">               
                <TextBox Text={binding Text} />        
                <Button Command={binding ClickCommand} />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And you set the data context of your window to itself by putting this line in the window constructor bellow the `InitializeComponents` call

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

This is a correct approach to dynamic control creation in WPF. One step further is to use MVVM and do the jobs in ViewModels which is an even better approach.

I hope I could help you in solving your problem.

Comment: I got the error "binding is not supported in a WPF project". changing it to capital B Binding worked though? :S