# Simple order form C# buttons not changing labels

Tags: c#, label, checklistbox

I am trying to create a simple generic order form. What would be the easiest way to do the check boxes so that when you click the boxes they are added to the $2.00 base price when added to cart and represented in the texboxt on the right. I also tried to just change the text of the Total Label when button clicked but it would not change when running. Any Ideas? I attached the picture of the design form so it makes it a little easier to see where I'm trying to go with things.

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Cake_Coffee_Ordering
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    //Add coffee to cart button
    private void Button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = " Change in label";
    }
    //clear right richtext box and total label
    private void Button2_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = " ";
    }
    //checkout popup alert with total and message
    private void Button3_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Total here");
    }

    private void tabPage1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: So, you don't tried anything, but want that us to do your work?

Comment: So you want us to fill in those blank vent handlers?  Why dont you try something and then ask for help *if* you get stuck.  Its your homework and its meant for you to learn something which happens from writing code and doing research.  Read [ask] and take the [tour] please

Comment: Well if you read my question you would see that I did try something I just did not post it. For the label change when a button is clicked shouldn't I be able to do {label.Text = "changed text here";:

Comment: If you had read [ask] and taken the [tour] you'd know that you need to show some effort in your post - we cannot help with code we cannot see.

Comment: you need to put an action on AddCoffee button and do something there : add selected item in your gridList and Total.Value += itemPrice (something like that) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102760/wpf-button-click-in-c-sharp-code

Comment: So for the time being I am just trying to get it to change the label. however when I try and just to a simple label text change it does nothing when ran? I updated with what I was tooling with. Isnt the action the Button1_click?

Comment: Try attaching the click event to the handler in the "Initialization" portion of the form (as I can't tell from this if it's actually attached to the button's click event) in such as manner as "Button1.Click += Button1_click;".

Comment: @Dr_FeelGood thanks! that was the question I was after, just wasn't sure how to word it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my above answer in the comments, ensure the button's click event has a handler attached to it.

Such as:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Button1.Click += Button1_click;
    }
```

You can also set this via the designer by double clicking the control to automatically create the event handler in your code and then modify that. Or you can use the properties panel to do this as well (either select a handler you've created or double click the field to create a new one):

[image]

Given your code, that should be the only reason this isn't firing, unless something else is hidden from us that we can't comment on further. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Its firing now, but I am failing to under stand why it doesn't like having richTextbox1.Text = " "; with label5.Text =" "; underneath the button click. it will only fire the first richtextbox clear and will not clear label 5?

Comment: Debug the code and see what the label text changes to when after it passes over that break point (step through - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger#set-a-breakpoint-and-start-the-debugger). Are you also setting the text for label5 somewhere else as well?

Comment: I found it, I forgot to comment a piece of code out so it was calling it somewhere it shouldn't have been so it skewed the clear.

Comment: Sounds like you're solid then, I'd definitely appreciate you marking this as the correct answer if it solved the above question you had. Happy coding!