# Handling a custom control event from the parent window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a **custom control**, lets call it **uc_mycontrol**, inside this control, I have a button lets name it **btn_demo**.
So in my **mainwindow.xaml** , i have an instance of the **uc_mycontrol**.  I want to use the **btn_demo** click event handler, but I want to declare the event handler within the **mainwindow**'s class, rather than declaring the event handler in **uc_mycontrol**'s class. I know that the best way to handle the click event is by defining it inside **uc_mycontrol** but I specifically want to handle this event on the  mainwindow

In summary, I have a custom control, with a button on it. I have instantiated the custom control on a window. I want to handle the button click event within the window, rather than from within the custom control.

Comment: Which information, that is not here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102760/wpf-button-click-in-c-sharp-code,  are you missing?

Comment: That is not even remotely close to what i need

Comment: ok, than i misunderstood your explanation of the problem...

Comment: Thanks anyway.. i appreciate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom event in your uc_mycontrol. Then, on bt_demo click event, very if the custom delegate has subscribers. If yes, fire the custom event.

```
public partial class uc_mycontrol : UserControl
{
    public delegate void MyControlClickEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e);
    public event MyControlClickEvent OnControlClickEvent;

    public uc_mycontrol()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.OnControlClickEvent?.Invoke(sender, e);// sender = the button
        //this.OnControlClickEvent?.Invoke(this, e); // sender = this control
    }
}
```

Add your custom control to `MainWindow.xaml` and subscribe to the custom event.

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverFlowWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverFlowWPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <local:uc_mycontrol HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="293" Margin="89,64,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="547"
                        OnControlClickEvent="uc_mycontrol_OnControlClickEvent">
    </local:uc_mycontrol>
</Grid>
```

In your `MainWindow.xaml.cs`, you will have:

```
private void uc_mycontrol_OnControlClickEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Message");
}
```